# How to retrieve filename from ls output

Tags: bash

I'm trying to automate the selection of a usb interface on macOS for avrdude. I want to select the first output of `ls /dev/tty.usb*`.

I'm trying to automate [this](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J36/5.b).

However, I can't seem to get `cut` to work, and other solutions to similar problems are unfortunately too complex for me abstract to my problem. It would seem something like `awk` or `sed` is the correct approach, but I am not familiar with either of these.

For example, I want to get `/dev/tty.usbmodem002021332` from running

```
$ ls /dev/tty.usb*
/dev/tty.usbmodem002021332  /dev/tty.usbmodem002021334  /dev/tty.usbserial-DAYO5CGB
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your struggles with the output `ls` are an example of why it's never a good idea to rely on `ls` within a shell script.  In order to fetch the list of files that match the pattern, `/dev/tty.usb*`, an alternative is to assign the result of a glob expression to an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
list=(/dev/tty.usb*)
```

...and then fetch its first element:

```
echo "${list[0]}"
```

For more on why `ls` is problematic, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: If you need portability to shells that don't have array support, you can use a function instead: `firstmatch() { echo "$1"; }; device=$(firstmatch /dev/tty.usb*)`

Comment: This is a tricky one to make 100% reliable.  Where `/dev/tty.usb*` doesn't match, it'll expand to `/dev/tty.usb*`.  Technically `firstmatch()` could only emit `$1` if a file exists with that name, however, if the first argument to `firstmatch` exists, it doesn't necessarily mean that it matches the glob.  Getting this totally right in a portable way...is kinda hard.  Since the question is tagged as Bash, it gives us an out to simply depend on `bash`.  To make it more clear that this solution requires `bash`, I'll prepend a `#!` line.

Comment: Hah, I thought about adding a note that it might just return the pattern if there's no match, but it hadn't occurred to me that a file existing by that name doesn't mean it matches the pattern! But I think that's only possible if the pattern includes bracket expressions (like `file[0-9].txt`), so patterns that only use the `*` and `?` wildcards should be safe if you add the existence test. (Well, extglob patterns would also cause problems, but they're bash-only anyway.)

Comment: If a file exists that has a name that is identical to the pattern, it would be difficult for `firstmatch()` to determine that it exists, but its name doesn't necessarily match the pattern.  I guess this is #shell-life, though:  Being ultra defensive, while balancing conciseness and maintainability with correctness.